# So marquee won't work without deprecated singleLine="true"?

Tags: android

Marquee works only with deprecated `singleLine`:

```
<TextView
            ...
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```

And doesn't work with `maxLines` = 1:

```
<TextView
            ...
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```

and always using `mTextView.setSelected(true);` of course

Comment: What conclusion you came at? I too faced the same problem. Setting `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:inputType="text"` (even tried `android:inputType="none"`) doesn't work. Only `android:singleLine="true"` makes the text moving.

Comment: @MonishKamble I use deprecated property `singleLine=“true”`